# how to change sprite sheet code

Tags: jquery, animation

can anyone help me with changing this code http://jsfiddle.net/simurai/CGmCe/

```
  .hi {
    width: 50px;
    height: 72px;
    background-image: url("http://files.simurai.com/misc/sprite.png");

    -webkit-animation: play .8s steps(10) infinite;
       -moz-animation: play .8s steps(10) infinite;
        -ms-animation: play .8s steps(10) infinite;
         -o-animation: play .8s steps(10) infinite;
            animation: play .8s steps(10) infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -500px; }
}

@-moz-keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -500px; }
}

@-ms-keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -500px; }
}

@-o-keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -500px; }
}

@keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -500px; }
}

<img src="http://files.simurai.com/misc/sprite.png" />
<div class="hi"></div>
```

so the animation stops at the last picture but more important that if I schould use another animation with exactly the same code structure it has to stop at the second animation, so it plays the first animation and the second animation fluently and stops at the last picture of the second animation.

Answer (score 0):

To play animation once replace `infinite` to `1`, i.e. [`animation-iteration-count`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation) property:

```
animation: play .8s steps(10) 1;
```

To add delay add number of seconds before `animation-iteration-count` attribute:

```
animation: play .8s steps(10) 2s 1;
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/CGmCe/4094/

Comment: Thanks but now the animation has to stand on the same place so it seems to be one animation, and the user has to be abel to choose if to play the animation only one time or also the second time

Comment: is it possible that you can answer my question or are you too busy?